# How do I connect 2 routers wirelessly?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have 2 routers here, one is a TP-LINK TL-WR885N (my main one) and the other is a Fast FW150R (slave I guess?). What would I need to do to connect the latter (FW150R) to the former (WR885N) wirelessly in an attempt to extend my wireless signal a little bit more? I'd prefer not to get a 50ft+ cable lol.

Thanks

Comment: Both need to support wireless bridging to do it, look up their manuals. But Homeplugs will be a better option 9 times out of 10.

Comment: @Linef4ult kk, figured i'd put this thing to good use, but might have to go with that instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your routers needs to have the ability to act as wifi client and wifi AP at the same time. From the quick and dirty search I did with the model numbers you've provided I doubt either one has that possibility.

What you need is a **wifi extender**. If you google the term you'll get an adequate amount of relevant results back.
One example to help you make your choice is: http://www.trustedreviews.com/best-wifi-extenders_round-up
For some additional background information which is correct and succinct enough for the current setting (for example it lacks the mention of dual radio repeaters which can reduce the drawbacks) is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_repeater

Comment: thanks, i'll look into that, does an extender require any sort of setup? or do i just need to plug it in and it'll automatically pick up signals and rebroadcast?

Comment: Depending on the hardware you have and will buy you'll need to do a minimal amount of setup (when both support wps for example) or a manual configuration to connect the extender to the existing wifi router's SSID. As usual, functionality and price are directly related to each other.